# Facing weird problem while trying to convert JSON string into JavaPOJO

Tags: java, json, pojo

### Maven Dependancy - Eclipse IDE

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

### Without any annotation, I am getting

### Console Error

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "id" (class com.optimight.prakash.general.Employee), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: (String)"{"id":1,"name":"Lokesh Gupta","age":34,"location":"India"}"; line: 1, column: 8] (through reference chain: com.optimight.prakash.general.Employee["id"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:823)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1153)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1589)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1567)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:294)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004)
    at com.optimight.prakash.general.JSONtoJavaPOJO.main(JSONtoJavaPOJO.java:18)

### With annotation:  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

in Employe Class , then I am getting

Employee [id=null, name=null, age=null, location=null]

### Application Class - Main Method

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JSONtoJavaPOJO {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Lokesh Gupta\",\"age\":34,\"location\":\"India\"}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try
    {
        Employee emp = mapper.readValue(json, Employee.class);

        System.out.println(emp);
    }
    catch (JsonGenerationException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

### Employee Class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;



//@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Employee
{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private String location;



    public Employee() {
    }


    public Employee(Integer id, String name, Integer age, String location) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.location = location;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age
                + ", location=" + location + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you not have any setters or getters in your `Employee` class?  How are you getting the data back out with private members and no getters?  Anyway, I suspect that Jackson is using the no-arg constructor to instantiate your object, and is then unable to set any of the values because there are no setters.  Try adding setters and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @Jordan Added Setters; problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add setters and getters to your Employee class.

Answer (score 0):

You may use project lombok to add setters & getters. Final Employee class will look this.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Employee
{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private String location;
}
```